# Making a lisp function that adds text between visual line mode

Tags: org-mode

So, i was wondering how would I write a function that inserts text between visual line block,
i would basically want to add `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` between the code in my org files efficiently, so i find this functionality would be very helpful

Okay, so lets put it like this: I have the following 3 lines of code that i want to visually select:
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
I want a functionality that can insert text at the beggining and end of visually selected text, like this, for example:
#+begin_src dumbcode
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
DUMBCODEBLOCKTOBEVISUALLYSELECTED
#+src_end –

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Inasmuch as `visual-line-mode` does *not* modify any text that might be inserted into the buffer, that minor-mode appears to be irrelevant to the question.  I.e., only the on-screen appearance of the text is affected by said minor-mode.  Please edit the question to clarify exactly what is needed, e.g., simply wrap existing text with the prefix / suffix used in org-mode source code blocks?

Comment: Assuming that `visual-line-mode` is irrelevant to the question, as per @lawlist's comment, I think what you need is `org-insert-structure-template` (bound to `C-c C-,` in GUI Emacs - in terminal Emacs it is bound to `C-c C-x s` because you generally cannot type `C-,` in a terminal). You mark the region normally and the command will surround it with a template of your choice (`s` for a source block, `e` for an example block, etc.)

Comment: In addition to describing abstractly what you want to accomplish, you should always add a simple, but representative, example: "Suppose I have an Org mode buffer with some program text <show the program>. I want to turn it into an Org babel source block, like this  <show what you want it to look like>".  A clear question will elicit a quicker and better answer - guaranteed.

Comment: i've posted an answer to this thread in a better format, because i couldnt format the previous comment in a proper fashion with mini md.
Sorry for the late response as well :)

Comment: Don't continue your question with a pseudo-answer. **EDIT** your question to make it clear. And please delete the non-answer you added. Thx.

Comment: Done, the question is updated and explained in a better fashion, i reckon.